# "Variable is not defined" when trying to assign checkbox to an action with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I'm new to Python or programming .
I'm trying to bind tkinter checkbox to a command but have issues .

I have created an app that should save data to xlsx file based on the user input . When the user choose the relevant options they should be "Activated" however I get an error when I click on the relevant checkbox (Assigned command to one for now just to check if it works).

Below is my entire code and below the code I have added the error I get . I also add the GIU window so you see how it looks and what I mean exactly .

I found one or two threads discussing this issue however I don't think the source of the issue is the same . I'm using Python 3.9 with Anaconda and Spyder

The relevant  code :
.

```
  from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from termcolor import cprint ,colored
import pydicom
import pandas as pd




class gettingDataFromDICOM:
    def DICOMData(dcmread):
        pass
    #Asking the user to choose input location
    print('Welcome to DTETool v1.1')
    

def filelocainput():
    global Data
    filelocationinput = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    Data = pydicom.dcmread(filelocationinput , force = True )
    



    print('PatientID -',Data.PatientID)
    
    
    df = pd.DataFrame ({'PatientID ': [Data.PatientID]})

class tkgui:
    pass

def activate():
  if   Data.PatientID.get() == 1:
            scale.config(state=ACTIVE)
  elif Data.PatientID.get() == 0:
            scale.config(state=DISABLED)
     


Checkboxes =Tk()
Checkboxes.geometry('400x320')
TitleSelDCM = Label(Checkboxes , text ='DICOM fields selection',fg='white')
TitleSelDCM.place(y=0 ,x=120)
CheckboxWindowbg = PhotoImage(file="C:\Tools\DTETool\SeconderyBG.png")
CheckboxWindowbg_label = Label(Checkboxes , image=CheckboxWindowbg)
CheckboxWindowbg_label.place(y=0,x=0 , relwidth =1 , relheight=1)


CheckBoxPID = IntVar()
CheckBoxPID = Checkbutton(Checkboxes , text = 'PatientID', bg = '#0B5ED8' ,fg = 'white', onvalue = 1 , offvalue = 0  , variable = CheckBoxPID ,command =activate)
CheckBoxPID.place(y=20 , x=20)
Checkboxes.mainloop()
```

The error :

```
  Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Tools\DTETool\DTEToolv1.1\DTEtool.py", line 113, in activate
    if   Data.PatientID.get() == 1:
NameError: name 'Data' is not defined
```

[An image with the relevant parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wqzx.png)

Thank you !

Comment: Try adding `global Data` at the start of your `filelocainput` function.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply . I still get the same error .

Comment: first, don't import everything (don't use `*` when importing), also why do you import `tkinter` twice anyways? second, please provide a [mre]

Comment: If you would like to access `Data` within another function, you should pass it as an argument, or use it as a global variable. To make it global, you should declare it above `gettingDataFromDICOM`, and define it as `None`. To be able to modify it, you need to add `global Data` above, like @TheLizzard suggested. Before using `Data` in `activate` make a quick type check, if `Data` is `None`, no file were processed before, just return. Otherwise `Data` will be the thing you want it to be! I would not recommend the use of global variables thought, it refers to poor design.

Comment: Thank you . I'll look into it now . Also , I used @Matiiss suggestion and posted only the relevant part of the code .

Answer (score -1):

Edit: The problem is that you are not declaring the variable `Data` at the local scope, only in a function scope. Also pay attention that you are initializing `Data` inside the function `filelocainput` but you never call it.

Following the answer of [TheLizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11106801/thelizzard) from the comments, add a `global Data` statement inside the function `filelocainput` as the first statement. then find a proper place to call the function `filelocainput()` **before you should use `Data`**

Edit: The following is a small working example for the usage of `global`:

```py
def foo():
    global x
    x = 1

foo()
print(x)
```

In your code, it should look something like the following (skipping irrelevant parts):

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from termcolor import cprint ,colored
import pydicom
import pandas as pd

...

def filelocainput():
    global Data
    ....


filelocainput()
...
```

This should get it to work, as a simple solution to close the loop. However, this is not the only way, and for sure not the best practice.

Comment: The `global Data` at the start is useless. `global` is only needed when you are going to change the value of that variable and you are inside a function. In the first case of `global Data`, it isn't in a function, therefore it's useless.

Comment: @TheLizzard yes, you are correct! I will edit my answer

Comment: I still can't make it work . Maybe it's better to try different way ?